# Drupal "Jump To" Block Filtered by Terms with Children

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-blocks, drupal-exposed-filter

So, I'm working on a site right now in Drupal that has a block designed to allow a visitor to jump to different "projects" (just a term). Most of the projects have content associated with them. However, some projects become empty from time to time as content is moved around and projects are restructured.

I currently have a view in place that shows an exposed form listing all of these projects as a dropdown and displaying it in a block. Is there a way for me to customize this view to only show projects that have content associated with them?

This would preferably be done entirely with the view. However, I would love to see any solutions you all can come up with. Also, please excuse my terminology if any is incorrect. I'm very new to Drupal and still getting used to the labels and structure of the whole CMS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thx S/O!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Edit the view. Under the Advanced section => Relationships, click add.
2. Add the relationship "Taxonomy term: content with term", and make sure to check "Require this relationship".
3. If this makes your view full of duplicates, try [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/38457) to a question at drupal.stackexchange.com.

Hope that helps!